# How to get the Area of a Polygon with a known SpatialReference in arcobjects?

Tags: arcobjects

This is what I tried so far:

```
IGeoGraphicCoordinateSystem gcs= _spatialReferenceFactory.CreateGeographicCoordinateSystem((int)esriSRGeoCSType.esriSRGeoCS_WGS1984); 
ISpatialReference standardRef = gcs as ISpatialRef; 
double GcsConversionFactor = gcs.CoordinateUnit.ConversionFactor; 


void myFunc(IPolygon poly)
{
poly.Project(standardRef); 
IArea area = poly as IArea. 
double areaCoords = area.Area ; 

double AreaKM = areaCoords * (GcsConversionFactor * GcsConversionFactor ); //this is giving me nonsense answers

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your spatial reference is WGS84, which is a non-projected coordinate system (latitude and longitude).

You will need to reproject the geometry into a projected coordinate system. `IArea.Area` will then yield the area in the projected coordinate systems units.